# Using libGdx and Box2d for game and getting this error- "incorrect checksum for freed object"

Tags: libgdx, box2d, tilemap, asset-management

I am new in game development and I am using `libGdx` with `box2d` in my game, whenever I try to switch screen (both screens has box2d bodies with `Tiled map`), I encounter the following error.

> java(610,0x70000297a000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f8d642fd600: 
>    incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after  being freed.
>    *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

The code which I use to switch screen is in render method

```
if((mapPixelWidth - 200) <= frog.body.getPosition().x * PPM){
        game.gm.setPrefLevel(0);
        Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                Array<Body> bodies= new Array<Body>();
                world.getBodies(bodies);
                for (Body b: bodies) {
                    world.destroyBody(b);
                }
            }
        });
        game.manager.unload("maps/World1Level3.tmx");
        game.setScreen(game.levelLoading);
    }
```

Apart from this error, I want to ask that the way I am using `Asset Manager` and `Box2d` `bodies` are correct or not?

Comment: Why is there `postRunnable`?

Comment: That error probably means that you're trying to use a body after destroying it. When you've destroyed a body you should no longer keep any references to it.

Comment: @Spectre well i can't destroy a body without runnable because bodies can't be destroyed if world is locked, though its not a best way to destroy a body

Comment: @Charanor I am destroying all bodies before switching screen and creating new bodies in next screen